# How can I pictorially show an option is unavailable for a time?

Tags: buttons, response-time, time, options, trial-period

I have an option (a single button) in the settings, that won't be avaliable for the user for about 2 weeks.

I have considered a number of options:

1. Leave it out - make it suddenly appear
2. Keep it faded out, and become avaliable after the time
3. Have a countdown (this can vary based on user actions though).

I could go for one of the options, and none are awful but I wonder if there is a better option.

Comment: Please add a screenshot. Is this a menu item? A group of controls? A Web page? An entire microsite?

Comment: @tohster a single button. I don't have a screenshot as I've not put the menu together - I was planning all of it (including this bit) first.

Comment: is this a new functionality or one that is going to be suspended for 2 weeks?

Comment: @rewobs it will be a new functionality.

Comment: @Tim if it's a new functionality I'm not sure why you would want to introduce it but disable it beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

I have some questions for you:

- Are there business drivers that you're not mentioning, such as a legal requirement to deliver something that you don't yet have?
- Is there a reason users need to know about the feature in advance—for example to help them prepare their data or adjust their processes?
- Will this inactive control reframe their mental model of the software, so users have a better understanding of how to use the pieces that are already working?

Your case is a bit of an unknown to me, so here's some general advice:

- Think about the experience. How will it feel to users to know that this feature is **not** available, yet? Will they feel cheated or teased or frustrated? How do you *want* them to feel?
- One thing you probably won't want to do: provide an inactive control that sends users on a wild goose chase, as they attempt to discover why the control is inactive. You can make this clear with (temporary) text directly in the UI.
- Can you deliver part of the experience now, and the rest in two weeks? If the part you can provide can offer *meaningful* use, then you might consider that.

I hope some of this helps you make a decision.